# c# inherits an Interface with a derivate class in a method's parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   ...
}
```

and then i have a lot of classes that derive from `BaseClass`:

```
public class DerivedOne : BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

I need to implement an Interface that manage the possibility to implement a method that can uses alle the class derived from `BaseClass` like parameters:

```
public interface IErrorParser
{
    List<string> ParseErrorMessage(BaseClass base);
}
```

At this point, if i try to implement a class starting from the interface, in this way

```
public class FirstParser: IErrorParser
{
     public List<string> ParseErrorMessage(DerivedOne derived)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

i receive the error:

> FirstParser does not implement interface member
>   'IErrorParser.ParseErrorMessage(BaseClass)'

at this point i think that i need to use the generics... But i can't understand how...

Comment: It looks like you might want to make your interface generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `IErrorParser` interface generic like this:

```
public interface IErrorParser<T> where T:BaseClass 
{
    List<string> ParseErrorMessage(string defaultMessage, T service);
}
```

And then you can implement it like this:

```
public class FirstParser: IErrorParser<DerivedOne>
{
     public List<string> ParseErrorMessage(string defaultMessage, DerivedOne rerived)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you implement an interface **you must exactly match all interface members** (methods and properties) defined in it.

In your case you need to write

```
 public class FirstParser: IErrorParser
 {
      public List<string> ParseErrorMessage(string defaultMessage, BaseClass service);
      {
         ...
      }
 }
```

> An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers. A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: The question changed after my answer. Currently the answer of @Yacoub Massad best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface like

```
public interface IErrorParser<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    List<string> ParseErrorMessage(string defaultMessage, T service);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
public interface IErrorParser
{
    List<string> ParseErrorMessage(BaseClass base);
}
```

you can implement it in a class using DerivedClass like this

```
public class FirstParser: IErrorParser
{
     public List<string> ParseErrorMessage(BaseClass baseObj)
     {
        DerivedClass derived = (baseObj as DerivedClass);
        if (derived == null)
        {
           // handle null value
        }
        ...
     }
}
```

**Edit**
`base` is a keyword and you should not use it as the name of an argument.